# How to overclock 8 * NVIDIA 1080 8 GB GPU with Claymore on ethOS or Windows 10?

Tags: windows, claymore, nvidia

Do any Ethereum miners have experience overclocking Nvidia 1080 8 GB GPU’s using Claymore on Windows 10?  According to multiple conversations I’ve had today with experienced miners, even those utilizing liquid-coolers, it’s apparently easier said than done when compared to using Radeon 8 GB 580’s with Claymore on Windows 10.

I’ve attached my .bat file convention within the below markdown.  I’d sincerely appreciate any guidance since this is my first day officially mining Ethereum!  I’m throwing in the towel tonight and using ethOS on my next build with 8 Radeon 580 GPUs- from what I gather, the Linux .conf file convention should be much easier to modify for overclocking.

```
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100

EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool eth-us-west1.nanopool.org:9999 -ewal ehtaddress.name/email -epsw x -mode 0 -ftime 10 -allpools 1 -r 180 -etha 0 -tt 60 -tt -80 -mvddc -960 -mclock 1900
```

FYI, I’m currently averaging 272 Mh/s collectively and about 21.2 per GPU; please see below-screenshot.[image: hash-rate freqs]

Comment: Please do not suggest an overclocking application like MSI-Afterburner; I'm looking for the correct .bat file overclocking-convention that will yield >= 27 Mh/s.

Comment: I'm modifying my request for LINUX/ethOS local.conf parameters instead of Windows 10 .bat file parameters; please see below- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, folks- after subjecting my self to almost seven solid-hours of hacking around the BIOs and reinstalling Windows, I finally decided to switch gears into ethOS on another build configured with 8 * Radeon RX 580 Sapphire GPU's- and I nailed RIGHT OUT OF THE GATES with the below over-clocking parameters yielding >= 29.5 Mh/s per GPU, totaling 236 Mh/s!

```
maxgputemp 85
globalminer claymore
stratumproxy enabled
proxywallet ether-address.worker-name
proxypool1 pool-zone.your-pool.org:9999
proxypool2 pool-zone.your-pool.org:9999

flags --cl-global-work 8192 --farm-recheck 200

globalfan 90
globalcore 1750
globalmem 5100
globalpowertune 7
```

Although these parameters are customized for Radeon RX 580's, I re-formatted the subject build referenced in the post-question with ethOS; although I've yet to successfully overclock the 8 * NVIDIA 1080 GPUs >= 21.29 Mh/s, LINUX/ethOS is categorically much-easier and faster to spin-up and deploy than anything I've attempted to build with Windows 10- at default settings- or commenting-out the overclocking-parameters listed above for the Radeon RX 580-build (ie globalcore, globalmem and global fan).  I'll update this answer when successful.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I successfully overclocked the Asus Nvidia 1080 8 GB GPUs on a (Windows 10 * msi Afterburner) * (Claymore + nanopool) by achieving a hash-rate >= 191.Mh/s with the below params detailed in the screenshot.

- Core Voltage: 0%
- Power Limit: 100%
- Core Clock (MHz): 144
- Memory Clock: 456
- Fan Speed: Auto

[image]